# SQLAlchemy onupdate context.current_parameters breaking flow when content not being updated

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask application using SQL-Alchemy.
I have a particular field that is set to use a python method to modify it's content onupdate.

Code below:

```
def convert_markdown_to_html(context):
    #pdb.set_trace()
    return markdown2.markdown(context.current_parameters['content_markdown'])
```

And the model code:

```
class Event(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "event"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    event_name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    event_details = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, onupdate=convert_markdown_to_html) # will store html content
    content_markdown = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True) # the markdown of event_details
    event_date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    tickets_available = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    tickets_left = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    ticket_price = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    ticket_price_member = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    is_price = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    attendees = db.relationship('Event_records', backref=db.backref('attendees'))
```

The problem is, occasionally an event is updated without updating content_markdown.

When this happens the application breaks because

```
context.current_parameters['content_markdown']
```

doesn't exist

At the moment I am being stupidly hack-ish about this by including the following line wherever the event could conceivably be updated:

```
result.content_markdown = result.content_markdown + ' '
```

Ideally I would like to avoid polluting my description/content_markdown with potentially hundreds of blank spaces however I am not sure how to best avoid breaking the program.

I could do the conversion from markdown to html in the actual update method, and not in the model class, however this feels very un-OO for me as I am already using convert_markdown_to_html elsewhere in the model code (In situations that would never break my app, as the field is always updated).

Is there any way to effectively and cleanly avoid running the onupdate method should it's required content not be available?

With thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe make a check like : `if 'content_markdown' in context.current_parameters` in your `convert_markdown_to_html` method ?

Comment: This will not work. If we don't return anything, return value will be `None`, and as a result `event_details` field will be reset to `NULL`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?